# bookshelf documentclass causes error: Command '\SILmfont' already defined!

Tags: document-classes

I'm using Peter Flynn's `bookshelf` document class to produce a pdf "bookshelf", consisting of graphic representations of book spines with titles from my `.bib` file.

I followed the docs, and during the final XeLaTeX runs encounter this error:

```
Package fontspec Info: Font family 'Arial(0)' created for font 'Arial' with
(fontspec)             options [BoldFont={},ItalicFont={},SmallCapsFont={}].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"Arial/OT:script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 



./fontsel/8.tex:2: LaTeX3 Error: Command '\SILmfont' already defined!

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \def
        \SILmfontname{Arial}
```

Processing of my `.bib` file by the `prepdata.sh` script accompanying the documentclass produced, among other files, a subdirectory `fontsel` of my working directory containg files `1.tex`, `2.tex`, ..., `109.tex`.

*Each* of those `nnn.tex` files includes a line of the form `\def\SILmfontname{``}`.

What's wrong?

Here's the `test.tex` I'm using with my `.bib` file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass[a0paper,landscape]{bookshelf}
\addbibresource{books.bib}
\begin{document}\raggedright
%%\immediate\write18{./prepdata.sh}
\input{entries.tex}
\nocite{*}
\par\vfill\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the same as the distributed file except that I've used the name of my own `.bib` file and, per the docs, before the final two runs of `xelatex` uncommented the line `\input{entries.tex}` there.

I presume that any properly-formatted `.bib` file should do here, as for now I'd rather not share my own (which is for a book in preparation). But I'll post it if *really* needed.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. You say:

>> Each of those nnn.tex files includes a line of the form \def\SILmfontname{}. <<

That's correct. See the PDF documentation, section 1.2.3 on p.6, bottom. The reason for using \def is because that command changes every time one of the numbered files is executed. 

Whereabouts in your .bib file is this happening? Can you see from the log file if this is happening on the first entry to be processed, or the second, or which?

Comment: @PeterFlynn: The first error occurs during the first of the final 2 XeLaTeX runs when it gets to the *first* entry to be processed (where it's trying to use `.fontsel/108.tex`, with the error there on the 2nd line `\def\SILmfontname{Verdana}`).

Comment: @PeterFlynn I can confirm this report. Note that the error is not caused by the `\def` line but by the repeated use of `\newfontface` with the same first argument.

Comment: Thank you. As the fonts are assigned at random on each run, the same font may by chance reoccur or not reoccur in some runs.

Comment: Still testing. I restricted the fonts to just four to force them all to be reused a lot, and it still runs to the end without error.

Comment: @PeterFlynn The problem is not that the same font is reloaded but that the font command is redefined multiple times (`\newfontface\SILmfont...`). This would fail in the same way in a document like `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec} \newfontface\x{Arial} \newfontface\x{Palatino} \stop`. So the weird thing to me actually is why it doesn't fail for you ;-)

Comment: Everything's fine if I put an additional group around `\makebook`.

Comment: @Robert Yes, I understand you, but I can't see why \newfontface shouldn't be infinitely usable: I would expect it simply to overwrite the previous definition each time. In this package, it *has* to, because it needs to load a new font for each entry processed. If it used \csname to create a new *name* each time, it would soon run out of space.

Comment: In discussions with @murray, it may also be related to the actual number of fonts being used. But your idea of an extra group is excellent, thank you.

Comment: @Robert: The extra pair of braces in `bookshelf.cls` fixed things for me.

Answer (score 1):

Enclosing the content of the \makebook macro in an additional group (braces) appears to fix the problem. Thanks to @Robert for the suggestion and @murray for the groundwork.

A new version will be released shortly.

Comment: A better idea would be to use `\setfontface` or `\renewfontface` instead of `\newfontface` which as the name implies is for a new font command.